# How can I insert image between text in sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

I would like to learn how an image is inserted between words such as:

```
Lorem ipsum :imageshouldcomehere: dolor sit amet.
```

Is it possible in sphinx? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-definitions) should answer your question.

```
Lorem ipsum |image_reference| dolor sit amet.

.. |image_reference| image:: <path/to/img>
```